# Why does Rust require ownership annotations instead of inferring it?

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

How come Rust does not fully infer ownership of its variables? Why are annotations needed?

Comment: What are "ownership annotations"? Do you mean like how `self` and `&self` are different ways to write a method? Or do you mean lifetime annotations?

Comment: @trentcl Good link, thanks! I guess the rationale is similar, that full inference is in principle possible but maybe not desirable for usage purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that were even possible I believe it would be a terrible user experience because:

- if the compiler cannot deduce ownership of an object, the error can barely be understood (like with trial-and-error approach in C++ templates [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/generate-the-longest-error-message-in-c));
- the ownership policy doesn't seem to be easy to grasp (that's one opinion though) and trying to understand which semantic has been chosen by a compiler may lead to unexpected behaviors (reference a Javascript weird type conversions);
- more bugs during refactoring can be introduced (implied by the point above);
- full program inference would definitely take a huge amount of time, if it is even a solvable problem.

However, if you struggle with a lack of polymorphism, it is usually possible to parametrize a method with an ownership kind, which might be considered a somewhat explicit alternative to inference, e.g.:

```rust
fn print_str(s: impl AsRef<str>) {
    println!("{}", s.as_ref());
}

fn main() {
    print_str("borrowed");
    print_str("owned".to_owned());
}
```

Comment: Hm, well full inference does not contradict optional annotations. But it really has to work fully without any annotations.

Comment: More open question here (but unanswered): https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47126/is-full-ownership-inference-possible